# Asp.Net Core Magic File that allows Upgrades

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I know this exists as I had found it recently after core was announced, and I have actually done it in the past. I just cannot remember a specific file name.

When Asp.Net Core 1.0 or 1.1 was out, there was a feature in the IIS module that would watch the root directory for a special `.html` file with a certain name.

If that file appeared, it would shutdown the Core app, and serve that HTML file. This enabled you to cleanly upgrade without having to find and kill processes. When the upgrade was done, you remove the file and the process starts.

**I cant remember the required filename**

I'm also not sure that this feature has been included in newer versions of the `aspNetCore` IIS module.

Anybody remember this?

Comment: `app_offline.htm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well documented as `app_offline.htm`,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#app_offlinehtm

Comment: Thank you so much. I googled for a while and I just couldn't come up with it.